Copy Data From Sheet 2 If Not Found in Sheet 1
I have this code to copy the row data if the data in sheet "Update" is not found in sheet "Existing". The code was work perfectly fine, but idk why it copied all the data and ignoring the If Statement.
What the code do:

Browse and import data from another workbook to Sheet "Update"
Look based on column A in both Sheet "Update" and "Existing". If data in Sheet "Update" is not found in Sheet "Existing" THEN copy the row to Sheet "HIDE"

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
   'Import Data
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim openbook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        openbook.Close False
    End If
   
   Dim Cl As Range, Rng As Range
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
   'copy row yang ada di sheets 2 tapi gaada di sheets 1 ke sheets 3
   
   Set ws1 = Sheets("Existing")
   Set ws2 = Sheets("Update")
   Set ws3 = Sheets("HIDE")
   With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      For Each Cl In ws1.Range("A2", ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         .Item(Cl.Value) = Empty
      Next Cl
      For Each Cl In ws2.Range("A2", ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         If Not .exists(Cl.Value) Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = Cl Else Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cl)
         End If
      Next Cl
   End With
   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
      Rng.EntireRow.Copy ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
   End If
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Is there anything wrong in this code? Thank you

Import Data and Copy Non-Existing

If you meant that your code is copying all 'non-existing' data (including the previous) from sheet Update to sheet HIDE, it is because you're referencing all data in sheet Update instead of only the newly copied data:
For Each Cl In ws2.Range("A2", ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


To correct this, replace "A2" with "A" & FirstAvailableRow which you must determine before copying the source data.


Source/Existing

Update/HIDE Before

Update/HIDE After


If you run the code again, you'll copy the same data again. To kind of prevent this, you can use a message box at the end of the code. To seriously prevent copying the same data to sheet HIDE, you can implement a similar dictionary idea as you implemented for sheet Existing. You will have to do it if some of the newly added data could exist in sheet HIDE.
Let me know if the previously mentioned change is necessary and if copying only values to sheet HIDE is an option (to improve efficiency) so I can update the code.

The Code
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    
    ' Select the source file to open.
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant: FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", _
        Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    If VarType(FileToOpen) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub ' dialog canceled
    
    ' Create references to the destination workbook and its worksheets.
    Dim wbThis As Workbook: Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsExisting As Worksheet: Set wsExisting = wbThis.Sheets("Existing")
    Dim wsUpdate As Worksheet: Set wsUpdate = wbThis.Sheets("Update")
    Dim wsHIDE As Worksheet: Set wsHIDE = wbThis.Sheets("HIDE")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Import the values (no formats or formulas) from the 1st worksheet
    ' of the (closed) source workbook to sheet 'Update', starting
    ' with the first available cell in column 'A' (of sheet 'Update').
    ' Also, create a reference to the imported range.
    Dim rgUpdate As Range
    With Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen).Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
            Set rgUpdate = wsUpdate.Range("A" & wsUpdate.Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
            rgUpdate.Value = .Value
        End With
        .Worksheet.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    ' Create a reference to the populated cells
    ' in column 'A' of sheet 'Existing' excluding the header.
    Dim crgExisting As Range:
    With wsExisting
        Set crgExisting = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    ' Return the values in a 2D one-based (single-column) array
    ' (assumes at least 2 cells!).
    Dim DataExisting As Variant: DataExisting = crgExisting.Value
    
    ' Create a reference to the imported cells
    ' in column 'A' of sheet 'Update'.
    Dim crgUpdate As Range: Set crgUpdate = rgUpdate.Columns(1)
    ' Return the values in a 2D one-based (single-column) array
    ' (assumes at least 2 cells!).
    Dim DataUpDate As Variant: DataUpDate = crgUpdate.Value
    
    Dim urgUpdate As Range, r As Long
    
    ' Create a reference to a new dictionary object.
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case
        ' Populate the dictionary with the unique values from column 'A'
        ' of sheet 'Existing'.
        For r = 1 To UBound(DataExisting, 1)
            .Item(CStr(DataExisting(r, 1))) = Empty
        Next r
        ' Combine the imported cells (in column 'A' of sheet 'Update'),
        ' whose values are found in the dictionary, into a unioned range.
        ' If it were possible to just copy values to sheet 'HIDE',
        ' the efficiency of the remainder of the code could be vastly improved
        ' by using arrays!!!
        For r = 1 To UBound(DataUpDate, 1)
            If Not .Exists(CStr(DataUpDate(r, 1))) Then
                If urgUpdate Is Nothing Then
                    Set urgUpdate = crgUpdate.Cells(r)
                Else
                    Set urgUpdate = Union(urgUpdate, crgUpdate.Cells(r))
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End With
    
    ' Copy the entire rows of the combined cells from worksheet 'Update'
    ' to worksheet 'HIDE', starting with the next available cell in column 'A'.
    If Not urgUpdate Is Nothing Then
        With wsHIDE
            urgUpdate.EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub

